# Push Tag to all Containers in a GTM account

Tags: google-tag-manager

Is it possible to save a single tag to all containers within a Google Tag Manager account? For example: I want to add a HTML tag to all containers (200 individual containers within a single GTM account), is there any way around having to manually add the tag 200 times?

Comment: One still manual, but slightly less annoying process would be to create a container with the new tag and associated variables and triggers, and import it with the merge option to all containers. You'd still have to go through all containers, but at least it would be only one operation each and might be a reasonable middle ground between doing all by hand and developing an API solution. But you should look at sdhaus and give Simo's gtmtools a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is through using the Google Tag Manager API. The easiest form to do this is to use [GTM Tools](http://www.gtmtools.com/) - created by [Simo Ahava](https://www.simoahava.com/about-simo-ahava/) - which allows for tags to be added to 'cart' and then copied to accounts. This still has to be done for every individual container, though it might speed up the process.

If you have experience with the Google Tag Manager API, you could retrieve all Container ID's and loop through them to save the HTML tag. Though this is obviously more complex.

Comment: This sounds like the best option. I haven't used the GTM api but I have used adwords / analytics, I assume I have to get a similar dev token, either way this is significantly faster. Thanks.